# JavaScript Not Working in Firefox in a php file

Tags: php

I have a code in the code file.php
I've tried in the two browsers. For chrome, is working normally but in firefox not.

I do not understand if this only happens on firefox mine or globally.

I did not include this code because it is very long. Please help and if you want to see an example, you can see on this page: http://britha.com/profile.php?id=1

Sample in Chrome
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7EufA.png)

Thank you for the advice given ..

Comment: We can't help you if you do not explain what you want, what is going wrong, what you have tried.

Comment: @Glubus - At Mozilla, the part that I marked in the image does not appear

Comment: The part of your website you just posted does show on my end, and I'm using firefox. Try updating your browser.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

What's wrong? I don't see any diff, no console error :)

Comment: but in my mozilla browser does not appear. What is perhaps because of my browser that is not on the latest version

Comment: Try reinstall your FF browser, may some problems occurred in extensions or settings.